# How to alter a return value when value of row is null

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have an SQL statement in a DA Class (Java). The method `getStagescore` is used to get all scores from a specific internship (method is in Dutch). I realized that some scores are `null`.

```
public ArrayList<Stagescore> getStagescore(int stageId) {
    ArrayList<Stagescore> stagescores = new ArrayList<Stagescore>();
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM stagescore INNER JOIN score ON stagescore.waarde = score.waarde AND stagescore.criteriumId = score.criteriumId inner join criterium ON score.criteriumId = criterium.criteriumId WHERE stagescore.stageId = ?");
        statement.setInt(1, stageId);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Stagescore stagescore = new Stagescore();
            stagescore.setStagescoreId(resultSet.getInt("stagescore.stagescoreId"));
            stagescore.setStageId(resultSet.getInt("stagescore.stageId"));
            stagescore.setCriteriumId(resultSet.getInt("stagescore.criteriumId"));

            stagescore.setValue(resultSet.getInt("stagescore.value"));


            Score score = new Score();
            score.setCriteriumId(resultSet.getInt("score.criteriumId"));
            score.setScorebetekenis(resultSet.getString("score.scorebetekenis"));
            score.setValue(resultSet.getInt("score.value"));

            Criterium criterium = new Criterium();
            criterium.setCriteriumId(resultSet.getInt("criterium.criteriumId"));
            criterium.setCriterium(resultSet.getString("criterium.criterium"));

            score.setCriterium(criterium);
            stagescore.setScore(score);

            stagescores.add(stagescore);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            statement.close();
            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
```

The question mark is for a given external value. Sometimes the values of `stagescore.value` are empty... How can I change the value from `stagescore.value` to 0 when it is null?

Comment: If there's an external value, you probably have an SQL client to supply and parse results. Please add the client's relevant code and tag (expected `php`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce()` (the ANSI standard function for this):

```
SELECT *
FROM stagescore inner join
     score
     on coalesce(stagescore.value, 0) = score.value and
        stagescore.criteriumId = score.criteriumId inner join
     criterium
     on score.criteriumId = criterium.criteriumId
where stagescore.stageId = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM stagescore 
   inner join score on IFNULL(stagescore.value,0) = score.value 
    and stagescore.criteriumId = score.criteriumId 
   inner join criterium on score.criteriumId = criterium.criteriumId 
where stagescore.stageId = ?
```

Comment: Would you consider elaborating on this to explain why this might solve the original question?

Comment: IFNULL(stagescore.value,0) sets to the first expression if the value of stagescore.value is not null otherwise sets to the second expression if the value of stagescore.value is null

Comment: it does not return a value if the two values doesn't match... so score.value has to be 0 when you want a return value

Comment: this was not your question. your question was "Sometimes the values of stagescore.value are empty... How can I change the value from stagescore.value to 0 when it is null?" so if the value for stagescore.value is null then only it will change to 0 otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

Before execute this Mysql command check whether variable contains value if else store 0 on this variable

```
if(!$variable)
$variable = 0;
```

Comment: There is no variable that is linked with stagescore.value... So this cannot be used.